# Find the value of $\int_{0}^{t} \frac{\cos2x}{\sqrt{t-x}}\, dx$

Tags: integration, laplace-transform

I'd like to fine  the value of $\int_{0}^{t} \frac{\cos2x}{\sqrt{t-x}}\, dx$, from my point of view Laplace is the best chose as follows

> $$\int_{0}^{t} \frac{\cos2x}{\sqrt{t-x}}\, dx= L(\cos2x\star\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}})$$

Any suggestion?  Thanks in advance

Comment: $\int_{0}^{t}\frac{\cos(2x)}{\sqrt{t-x}} = \left[\cos(2x) * \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\right](t)$, there should not be any $L$ in your highlighted identity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Just if you accept to consider other solutions than Laplace.*

Let $$\sqrt{t-x}=u \implies x=t-u^2\implies dx=-2 du$$ which make
$$\frac{\cos(2x)}{\sqrt{t-x}}\, dx=-2 \cos \left(2 \left(t-u^2\right)\right)\,du$$ Now, expanding 
$$\cos \left(2 \left(t-u^2\right)\right)=\cos(2t)\cos(2u^2)+\sin(2t)\sin(2u^2)$$ which lead to Fresnel integrals.

Provided $t>0$, the final result should be 
$$\int_{0}^{t} \frac{\cos(2x)}{\sqrt{t-x}}\, dx=\sqrt{\pi } \left(C\left(\frac{2 \sqrt{t}}{\sqrt{\pi }}\right) \cos (2
   t)+S\left(\frac{2 \sqrt{t}}{\sqrt{\pi }}\right) \sin (2 t)\right)$$